# How to get urls for every image format in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I have a project deployed to heroku, and when both the local branch and the heroku have the same code, they still are returning different types of data for the image formats. The differences are explained below:

The local branch has the following format of data, where every format has a url that can be used to access the image.

[image]

The staging environment is giving the following type of data under every image format, which doesn't include any url, which is not required and there is no way to access the image of any particular format through this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have set the (Settings > Media Library >) Responsive friendly upload to `true` before uploading the image it will create the formats for you. The formats (and the settings for it) are stored in the database. Try cloning the database from one environment to the other together with the local uploads folder (probably you want something like S3 to store the images for you).

Comment: what if the option was turned off, and after a while i decided to set it to True, will that affect already uploaded images? or should I re-upload images to get responsive sizes?

Comment: @Kardon63 It will not affect the images that were uploaded previously, Only the images that are uploaded after setting the option to true will have the expected formats of media in it.

Comment: @NavneetKaur0111 so i need to re-upload them to get the responsive images right? or is there an easier way?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no feature that resizes all your images (in bulk). Re-uploading them would be one way to solve the problem.

Comment: You are right @Sjouke, All is want is that it generates correct sizes of the pictures when I upload them

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but maybe is usefull for someone.
You should ask the url during your request from server.
Here is example

```
const apiAddrss = "/api/your-api-address?locale=your-languge-if-applicable&filters[title-or-slug][$eq]=if-you-want-use-title-or-slug&populate=*,your-requested-component-if-your-requested-page-include-component,other-component,component-that-includes-photo.name-of-sub-component-if-applicable&populate=maincomponent-that-has-photo.sub-component-that-has-photo.name-of-phot-component"
```